# Symfony - Twig - Filter "localizeddate" doesn't work on DateTime

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm using twig and when I apply the filter

`{{tutoriel.dateCreation | localizeddate('medium', 'none') }}` on my datetime, I have this error :

```
The filter "localizeddate" does not exist in Video2LearnAdministrationBundle:VisualisationFicheTutoriel:fiche_tutoriel.html.twig at line 167
```

Where I'm wrong ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found the solution.

You should have the twig intl extension installed. if not, do `composer require twig/extensions`

You may activate the services in config.yml or services.yml file like that:

```
services:
    twig.extension.intl:
        class: Twig_Extensions_Extension_Intl
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: Also there must to be active `php_intl` extension in php environment.

Comment: In Symfony 4, do `composer require twig/extensions`, then go to `config/packages/twig_extensions.yml`, then uncomment the Intl line

Comment: Since 2020, this package is abandonned. It's recommended to use twig/intl-extra like Breaith's answer said.

Answer (score 8):

i use a new twig filter `format_date()` : https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/format_date.html

1. Install: `composer req twig/intl-extra`
2. Usages in twig:

```
created_at|format_date('full')
created_at|format_date('full', '', null, 'gregorian', 'fr')
created_at|format_date('none', 'MMMM Y', null, 'gregorian', 'fr')
```

Comment: In Symfony project, you must add it in config/services as explained in this answer post [how-to-install-the-intl-extension-for-twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25948853/how-to-install-the-intl-extension-for-twig)