# Set locale for Symfony 2.5 application (force locale)

Tags: php, date, symfony, locale

I would like to force locale for my Symfony 2.5 application to `ru_RU.UTF-8`. I want this locale to be used for `strftime()` function.

I have the following configuration in my `app/config.yml`:

```
framework:
    default_locale: "ru_RU.UTF-8"
```

I'm using the following code in one of my controllers to debug this:

```
//setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
var_dump(setlocale(LC_TIME, 0));
var_dump(strftime('%B', time()));
die();
```

When executed like this, it shows: `string(1) "C" string(6) "August"`.

However, when first line is uncommented it shows: `string(11) "ru_RU.UTF-8" string(12) "Август"`, so the locale is installed in the system and works correctly.

Ho do I make Symfony to always use locale specified in the config?

---

**$ locale -a**:

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
ru_RU
ru_RU.iso88595
ru_RU.utf8
```

Comment: If I correctly understand, the Symfony uses a locale for the translations (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html). In other words, it doesn't use function `setlocale()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locale setting for Symfony doesn't influence the PHP settings, it's only a Symfony setting.

You have to use `setlocale()` to configure PHP's locale. You can place this in the front controllers (`web/app.php` and `web/app_dev.php`) or create a listener for kernel.request.

Comment: Thanks, I've added `setlocale` to my front controllers as a workaround. I guess I will keep it that way for now. But, is there a way to configure PHP (FPM) to use some specific locale though?

Comment: @SlavaFominII you need to set the locale in the actually enviorment you are running in. In your shell (I'm assuming you're running unix/linux) do `locale -a` if the value doesn't match what you want then find your locale config file and add this to your /etc/default/locale `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` replacing en_US.UTF-8 with whatever you want for your locale .

Answer (score 0):

Any solution based on `setlocale()` (as in [@Wouter J's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25297211/1668200)) will sooner or later give you a headache, since it relies on the locale setting of the *current machine*. So whenever you switch server, it might stop working. And it can differ between your development and production server.

A better approach is to drop `strftime()` in favor of [`IntlDateFormatter::formatObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.formatobject.php):

```
\IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($entity->getTimestamp(), \IntlDateFormatter::FULL, 'de_AT');
```

This only requires that you have the PHP `intl` extension installed. There's also a [Symfony replacement for PHP's native `\IntlDateFormatter`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/intl.html) but I guess that's only necessary if you don't have the `intl` extension available.

For Twig you can use the [localizeddate](https://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intl.html) filter. Installation instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24390635/1668200